# How to order an array of objects in array of categories in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

I have the following array of objects

```
{
  "nome": "jose",
  "categoria": [
    { "id": "1" },
    { "id": "3" },
  ]
},
{
 "nome": "maria",
  "categoria": [
    { "id": "2" },
  ]
},
{
  "nome": "pedro",
  "categoria": [
    { "id": "1" },
  ]
}
```

I have to reorder in another array of categories. Something like this:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "pessoas": [
    {
      "nome": "jose",
      "categoria": [
        { "id": "1" },
        { "id": "3" },
      ]
    },
    {
      "nome": "pedro",
      "categoria": [
        { "id": "1" },
      ]
    },
  ]
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "pessoas": [
    {
      "nome": "maria",
      "categoria": [
        { "id": "2" }
      ]
    },
  ]
},
```

I have try with the function reduce(), but I couldn't because it is not an object, but a array of objects (categoria)

```
      const group = data.reduce((r, array) => {
        r[array.categoria.id] = [...r[array.categoria.id] || [], array];
        return r;
      }, {});
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: The argument to `reduce()` is an array, so I don't understand why you couldn't use it.

Comment: "I tried ..." please provide the try

Comment: @Barmar sorry, i edited

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for grouping by `id`. Inside of reduce, `categoria` is iterated as well for getting the needed `id`.

```js
var data = [{ nome: "jose", categoria: [{ id: "1" }, { id: "3" }] }, { nome: "maria", categoria: [{ id: "2" }] }, { nome: "pedro", categoria: [{ id: "1" }] }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        o.categoria.forEach(({ id }) => {
            if (!r[id]) r[id] = { id, pessoas: [] };
            r[id].pessoas.push(o);
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```